# Is there a way to bulk add rows into a DataTable?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a lot of data that I need to insert into a SQL table and I'd like to use SqlBulkCopy. I have millions of rows that need to be added to a DataTable and I seem to be bottle-necked because the only way I've found to add rows is to use `DataTable.Rows.Add(DataRow);` This is an example of the code I've got so far:

```
var table = new DataTable("MyTableName");
table.Columns.Add("Id");
table.Columns.Add("SomeOtherColumn");

IEnumerable<MyObject> myData; // this is a method parameter which has millions of values
var rows = myData.Select(data =>
{
    return data.SomeInnerEnumerable.Select(e =>
    {
        var row = table.NewRow();
        row["Id"] = e.Id;
        row["SomeOtherColumn"] = e.SomeOtherColumn;
        return row;
    });
}).SelectMany(r => r); // flattens IEnumerable<IEnumerable<DataRow>> into IEnumerable<DataRow>

Console.WriteLine("DataRows created");

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

The code prints out `"DataRows created"` very quickly, but hangs up on the loop for 25+ minutes. Is there a more efficient way of adding this many rows to a DataTable?

Comment: With "millions of rows" of data, it seems like a micro ORM might be a better idea (faster) than a datatable

Comment: We've been using Dapper but determined that using SqlBulkCopy is leagues faster.

Comment: I think instead of the loop, you should be able to use `table.Rows.AddRange(rows);`

Comment: @Dortimer `DataRowCollection` does not have an `AddRange` method and the `Add(Object[])` method only creates 1 row https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: If you have access to the db schema/instance and can add _table value parameters_ to it, you'll see huge improvement - check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)

Comment: You should populate data tables with a [data adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter).

Comment: @GertArnold The DataTable is being populated from data in memory, not from a database.

Comment: Why are you using a `DataTable` and a SQL Table? `DataTable` isn't very lightweight...

Comment: Did you try BeginLoadData() and EndLoadData() before and after you add the rows? this remove all the checking and minitoring that data table do. if it still doesnt work I suggest to create xml string instead of the rows and then use ReadXml(). or try to create IDataReader.

Comment: Why do you use `DataTable`? Throw him out. Write directly from your `myData` source.